# Uploading file to Sharepoint List items

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I got a custom sharepoint list, with a title column which contains Servernames and i got alot of .csv files that has the same name as the title

Is it somehow possible to upload em to the list item as an attachment with a script? Maybe Powershell?
I got over 100 files so it would be a pain if i had to do it all manually.

The File and Title column looks like this:

```
Title
Server1.domain.com

.csv
Server1.domain.com.csv
```

Have been looking around for quite a while but havent been able to find anything i could use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach:

1. Iterate over the SharePoint list items.
2. Load the corresponding CSV file by the `SPListItem.Title`
3. Add the file as attachment to the `SPListItem`.

Script:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://List/Location/Url
$l = $w.Lists["TheList"]

foreach ($item in $l.Items)
{
     $file = Get-Item "$($item.Title).csv"
     $stream = $file.OpenRead()
     $buffer = New-Object byte[] $stream.length
     [void]$stream.Read($buffer, 0, $stream.Length)

     $item.Attachments.AddNow($file.Name, $buffer)
}
```

Considerations:

1. Disposing of the file stream
2. Disposing of the `SPWeb` object
3. Handle missing files

**Edit**

Two mistakes in first attempt:

1. `SPAttachmentCollection.Add` expects a byte array.
2. `SPAttachmentCollection.AddNow` should be used to add the attachment directly (without update of the `SPListItem`)

Updated the code...

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks for the quick answer, i'm getting following error. 
Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "System.IO.FileStream", for "Add" to type "System.Byte[]": "Cannot convert the "System.IO.FileStream" value of type "System.IO.FileStream" to type "System.Byte[]"."
At C:\Scripts\Upload Attachment.ps1:7 char:27
+      $item.Attachments.Add <<<< ($file.Name, $file.OpenRead())
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated the question.

Comment: Thanks alot Stefan! Its Working.
Last question: is there a way for the script to remove an attachment from the item if there already is a file before it uploads it?

Comment: Yes. Check out [`SPAttachmentCollection.DeleteNow Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spattachmentcollection.deletenow.aspx). Don't forget to accept the answer [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)